# Docker container not compling .tex file

Tags: python, docker, r-markdown, gitlab-ci

im trying to build a pdf artifact from a .qmd file via docker and a ci cd pipeline. in my qmd file is a tiny bit of python and the rest is only markdown.
Ill give my code first, then what i tried:
my dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app


ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libxt-dev
RUN R -e "install.packages('rmarkdown')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('roxygen2')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('XQuartz')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('quarto')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('xaringan')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('knitr')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tinytex')"
RUN R -e "tinytex::install_tinytex()"
RUN R -e "install.packages('reticulate')"
RUN R -e "reticulate::install_miniconda()"


CMD ["Rscript", "-e", "rmarkdown::render('el-portfolio.qmd', output_format = 'pdf_document')"]
```

im working through a ci/cd pipeline on gitlab. i didnt set up the runners myself, so if its an issue with them, ill have to take it up with my supervisor. the image builds fine, and when the container runs, it throws this error:

```
Error: LaTeX failed to compile el-portfolio.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See el-portfolio.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

so, what i tried:
i made sure everything was installed, especially the tinytex package, since that seems to be contributing to the error. i really dont know what else to do to solve this - does anyone have any ideas? thanks so much!

Comment: What does `el-portfolio.log` say? And do you have an [mcve] of `el-portfolio.tex`?

Comment: i have no idea where the log is, i thought it was just the error that showed up in the terminal connected to the pipeline...

Comment: and for th eel-portfolio.tex, i dont have a version of it, because it is automatically created by docker and the ci/cd pipeline - i just have a .qmd file, and want to end up with a pdf. so i really dont know how to access to .tex file..i guess i could get it to save as an artifact if the docker container doesnt run?

Comment: Very hard to debug without a log, or an [mvce]... Can you render the `.qmd` file [locally on your machine](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html)?

Comment: Im using VScode with quarto on my local machine, and there it does render a pdf :)

Comment: Do you have docker installed locally so you can run the dockerfile with the qmd file on your machine? Or have you already done that and does that work as expected?